# Data Annotation valuecontext always null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-annotations

```
public class ExcludeChar : ValidationAttribute
    {
        string _characters;
        public ExcludeChar(string characters)
        {
            _characters = characters;
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _characters.Length; i++)
                {
                    var valueAsString = value.ToString();
                    if (valueAsString.Contains(_characters[i]))
                    {
                        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

[ExcludeChar("@#$",ErrorMessage = "Please select a option.")]
        public string LSESelected1
        {
}
```

I am calling validations from one of ViewModel class the without validationContext, validation works fine, if i check validationContext its always show's me null.

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls the `Validate` method?

Comment: @MikeEason I think there is not calling code, the validation is called by xaml. I've noticed the same behaviour not so lonmg ago, and never got to the bottom of it. I would be interested to see an answer to as well :)